# Create paths from list of files / parents in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, path

I have a list of files in BigQuery. A very simplified table would look like:

| Name | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| First | / |
| Second | First |
| Third | First |
| Another | Third |
| This file | Third |
| Test | Third |
| FileA | Test |
| Last | FileA |

Is it possible to generate:

| Name | Path |
| --- | --- |
| First | / |
| Third | /First/ |
| Another | /First/Third/ |
| This file | /First/Third/ |
| Test | /First/Third |
| FileA | /First/Third/Test |
| Last | /First/Third/Test/FileA |

Answer (score 2):

Using **Recursive CTE**,

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE paths AS (
  SELECT *, '/' Path FROM sample_table WHERE Parent = '/'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*, p.path || t.Parent || '/' 
    FROM paths p JOIN sample_table t ON p.Name = t.Parent 
)
SELECT Name, Path FROM paths;`enter code here`
```

###### Query results:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+
|   Name    |           Path           |
+-----------+--------------------------+
| First     | /                        |
| Another   | /First/Third/            |
| FileA     | /First/Third/Test/       |
| This file | /First/Third/            |
| Test      | /First/Third/            |
| Last      | /First/Third/Test/FileA/ |
| Second    | /First/                  |
| Third     | /First/                  |
+-----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you!

That does function, but I am running this now on 29391 rows, and it does not seem to end :) Consuming days of slot time. It worked on a smaller set.